# How to create new cells when button on cell is pressed in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

*I want to insert new rows each time when add button is pressed ( condition: a valid email address is entered).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVR7j.png)
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
var totalCells=0
class AddEmailTableCell: UITableViewCell,UITextFieldDelegate {

    var obj:UIViewController=ViewController()
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var addEmailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addEmailImg: UIImageView!


    func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
        // print("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"

        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        addButton.isHidden=true
        self.textField.delegate=self
    }


    @IBAction func addEmailButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if(textField.text == nil || (textField.text?.isEmpty)! ) {

            print("email not filled")
            return
        }
        if (isValidEmail(testStr: textField.text!)==false){
            print("email not valid")
            return
        }
            totalCells=totalCells+1
        let index=IndexPath(row: totalCells, section: 0)
           (obj as! ViewController).tableView.insertRows(at: [index], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            print(totalCells)
            print("valid")

    }
}
```

My viewController code is given here:

```
 import UIKit
 class ViewController: 
   UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if totalCells==0{
        return 1
    }
    return totalCells
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addEmail", for: indexPath) as! AddEmailTableCell

    return cell

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
     }
 }
```

so what should i do here, I am calling tableview.reloadData and passing updated number of cells to my tableview, but it is not working.

Comment: You need a **model** (a data source array) in `ViewController` and you should move the *controller* related logic from the **view** (the cell) to the **controller**.

Answer (score 0):

You should move isValidEmail() and addEmailButton() to your ViewController and control tableview in this controller.